# How to split files based on varying number of lines in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to split a file into equal parts with the last file getting the left over records in Unix. For example: The file has 4 lines, I want to split into 4 files = awesome. 1 line per file.

I have 5 lines, I want to split into 4 files. What I really want here is this:

```
File - number of lines;
f1 - 1;
f2 - 1;
f3 - 1;
f4 - 2;
```

Is this even possible via a direct split command in Unix? I’m thinking not possible without some extra iterative coding around split?

Here's what I've tried:

```
numsplitfile=$parm (lets say 4)
total_lines=$(wc -l < $inputfile) (lets say the file has 5 lines)
lines_per_file = (total_lines + numsplitfile - 1) / numsplitfile)
split -l $lines_per_file $inputfile splitfilename
```

What this is doing is that it will convert to:

```
split -l 2 $inputfile splitfilename
```

hence giving me 3 files with 2, 2, 1 lines each. But what I want is 1, 1, 1, 2 lines in 4 files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on formatting. Its my first time here and about 2:45am where i m at :) so got a little hasty. This is in Bash. The main parameter is the required number of output files. I m trying to derive the number of lines per file with above code shown.

Comment: Excess to a leftover file instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/easy-way-to-split-a-large-text-file

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you won't be able to do it just with a split command, but you can work around it.
Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
inputfile=$1
parts=$2
total_lines=$(wc -l < "$inputfile")
lines_per_file=$[$total_lines / $parts]

rm out*  2>/dev/null
split -d -l $lines_per_file "$inputfile" out

extra_files=$(printf "out%02i\n" `seq $parts $[$parts * 2 - 1]`)
last_file=$(printf "out%02i\n" $[$parts - 1])
cat $extra_files >> $last_file   2>/dev/null  # ignore errors
rm  $extra_files                 2>/dev/null  # ignore errors
```

Name it `split_file` then you can call it like this:

```
$ ./split_file input_file 4
```

Split files will be called `out00` `out01` `out02` etc...

Comment: actually this simple command worked for me:
split -n l/4 input.txt splitfile

here l/4 being small L and not 1
and 4 being the number of output files that I need split into.

Comment: Interesting, i didn't know about `split -n l/4`. I'm getting strange results with it though, with a 7 line file the extra lines don't go to the last chunk as doc says it should. Might be a bug with this version (ubuntu coreutils 8.21).

Comment: Yes i found that too. It looks like its doing a round robin (although there is anohter 'r' option for round robin), try with 20 lines and split into 3 files and 4 files and 5 files. u will see the difference.